# PushRegistry.registerAlarm when phone is power off

Tags: java-me, midp

I'm developing a J2ME application, that is supposed to starts at each hour.

I'm using the `PushRegistry.registerAlarm` method, and it is working fine. Even if I turn off the phone, and turn on it still works.

The problem is: If the phone stays turned off for more than one hour, when the phone is switched on, the time of the alarm has passed out. And the application is not notified that is to start.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to the alarm call my midlet even if the actual time has passed from the scheduled time?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one deals with phone being off, MIDlet having to "memorise" something when it does not run and other stuff that needs, well, *persistence*, first thing that comes to mind is [MIDP rms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rms/info),

> ...Record Management System API, a persistent storage mechanism, through which MIDlets can persistently store data and retrieve it later.

For your case, it looks pretty simple: use the RMS to keep the **time of next expected notification**, like

1. at every notification your MIDlet does,
   replace current value of next-expected time with one for next notification
2. at `startApp` (or periodically by timer task / or by some background thread, whatever),
   check the value in RMS and find out if there was a missed (not removed) expected event

Comment: Hi Gnat, thanks for the answer. I already have a RMS persistence on my application, I can store the next-expected start time there. But if the phone stays powered off for more time than my next start-time registered by registerAlarm(), the app will not start when the phone be switched on. What you said is to detect if the alarm was not triggered, but this detection will happens only on the next user execution of the application. Will not be detected automatically. Neither the application will starts automatically, isn't that?

Comment: @Derzu well that would be a different / separate question than how you worded it originally (and quite an interesting one I think). MIDP 2 API (JSR 118) doesn't support autostart, one would have to use vendor-specific stuff for target device if there is any, or switch to MIDP 3, again, if target device supports it